# Invalid configuration object - Webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm pretty new to Webpack and trying to use the Twitter API in a project. Everything works fine until I require the twitter dependencies and the configuration file. Then I get the following error messages:

```
Can't resolve 'fs'
Can't resolve 'net'
Can't resolve 'tls'
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack-4-setup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "twitter": "^1.7.1"
  }
}
```

config.js

```
module.exports = {
   consumer_key: '',
   consumer_secret: '',
   access_token_key: '',
   access_token_secret: ''
}
```

index.js

```
const Twitter = require('twitter');
const config = require('./config.js');
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I've searched for an answer but can't find any that explains what's wrong. I found an answer in adding

```
node: {
    net: "empty",
    tls: "empty"
}
```

in webpack.config, but that gives another error: `Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.`

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong and what is going on here? I would be very thankful!

project file structure:

```
project
-dist
---main.js
-index.html
-node_modules
-package-lock.json
-package.json
-src
---config.js
---index.js
-webpack.config.js
```

Comment: main question is are You going to making backend app or frontend app? Net, tls, fs are core modules of nodejs and if You think that webpack will bundle node stuff - You're wrong. So please add more explanation about architecture of app and file structure (screenshot of files, folders)

Comment: My file structure is:
project
-dist
---main.js
-index.html
-node_modules
-package-lock.json
-package.json
-src
---config.js
---index.js
-webpack.config.js

It's a frontend app

Comment: ok, so You must understand that the package `twitter` You trying to use is nodejs module and it's working on serverside app. In another words You've to find clientside implementation of twitter or make Your own class.

Comment: But I've found several examples of using the twitter npm package with js and when I tried to run an example, it worked from the terminal but not from the browser. So you're saying it's not possible to use the npm package?

Comment: terminal is not a browser. You were executing js code in nodejs.

Comment: I found this https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals, if I understand correctly, Webpack should not bundle node_modules and this can help with that but when I try to use it I get error: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema. Can this be the problem?

Comment: Change Your question title: "Invalid configuration object - Webpack" to attract Webpack experts

Comment: I've done that. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You misunderstand what wepback-node-externals is. This will just tell webpack not to compile certain bundles, because they are available at runtime (like `fs` in nodejs). This won't make them available in the browser. like @num8er said, you need to find a different twitter sdk, or write one yourself.